# Compilation errors due to paths in OMNET++ Instant VEINS

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I am trying to compile a project as reference for my application in OMNET++ running in Instant VEINS virtual machine. The error is: `fatal error: 'MiXimDefs.h' file not found`

The 'MiXimDefs.h' file is located here: 'veins/src/base/utils/MiXimDefs.h' so it seems it's just path issues during compilation.

Reading from other threads on path issues, I have tried adding the exact location in the include line like this: `#include veins/src/base/utils/MiXimDefs.h'` but it is still giving me same error: `fatal error: veins/src/base/utils/MiXimDefs.h file not found`

What am I missing here aside from path issues? Maybe compatibility issues as well?

For reference I am using Instant Veins 5.2-i1:

Simulation modules

- Veins 5.2
- INET Framework 4.2.8
- SimuLTE 1.2.0 (plus a backported patch, 23c0936e31)
- Veins_INET included with Veins 5.2

Software

- OMNeT++ 5.7
- SUMO 1.11.0
- Cookiecutter 1.7.3 for cookiecutter-veins-project

Operating system

- Debian 11, Linux 5, GNOME 3